# How to make a random number same in 1 minute, and change after 1 minute in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to have the random numbers same in 1 minutes, which means in a minute I will have the same number which is random, and after 1 minute, I will get new random number the same for 1 minute, I need to use it 60 times same number every minute, any idea, thank you

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just check the clock to know whether you should get a new random number or repeat the previous one? Show your attempt..

Comment: generate a random and assign to a variable , then start a simple setinterval for 60k ms then generate a random and reassign to that variable, all the best

Comment: @alessandro he didn't say every 1/60 but every minute

Comment: @EugenSunic ok ok 60k ;)

Answer (score 1):

With this code, accessing `randomNumber` anywhere will give you the random number you seek, automatically changing every minute (`60_000` milliseconds).

```js
setInterval(() => globalThis.randomNumber = Math.random(), 60_000);
```

Comment: Wow! When has JS implemented that `60_000` syntax ?

Comment: "Hey, I think you meant `60000` instead of `60_000`. Could you edit the answer?"

Comment: @YannickK it actually works) In last Chrome, at least.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME oh my god, that is a disgusting thing I did not know about. I thought you were being sarcastic, my bad haha

Comment: P.s. found: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator ( Chrome 75+, Fox 70+, Safari 13+ )